# AngularJS custom directive isn't working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Tried a few different solutions, not sure where exactly I'm going wrong. I know the directive is linked properly, and have tried template instead of templateURL to test if it would work that way, but nothing.

Directive:

```
app.directive('printTasks', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '../printTasks.html'
};
});
console.log('printTasks is linked');
```

Calling in HTML:

```
            <section ng-controller="MainController">
                <header>This Week
                    <a href="">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-stack-2x fa-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                </header>
                <printTasks/>
            </section>
```

I've also tried  and that hasn't worked either.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

couple of points to be considered in above case of writing derictive -

1. You should use directive as element if using `restrict: 'E'` and should have custom attribute "info" as below
2. When you are using `replace:true` in directive then the template should have single root element. [More information](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt)

Answer (score 2):

It should be use camel case while using on html, also directive element shouldn't be self closing like `<printTasks/>`, as you have defined you own custom element.

```
<print-tasks></print-tasks>
```

Comment: So you use camel case to name a directive, then it gets converted to a hyphenated format? Changing it seemed to do something anyways, the directive is still not showing up, but the console is now showing the following error: http://i.imgur.com/h4ZH05a.png